# Twitter OAuth "Could not authenticate you" when I specify a callback url

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm having an issue with Twitter OAuth 1.0 during the `request_token` stage

If I set a `oauth_callback` of **oob** (or even omit the callback url) then it works fine, but then of course doesnt redirect the user to my web app afterwards.

**N.B. I may be going about this the wrong way. I just want to specify a URL that the client browser should be directed to after having authorized the OAuth request on Twitter**

As soon as I change the oauth_callback to my app's callback url, I get the error **"Could not authenticate you"**

I have setup the callback url in the app settings on twitter to exactly the same url as the one I am settings in the oauth_callback parameter of the request_token process which FYI is an HTTPS base url i.e. no path specified, https://www.example.com/

Any assistance would be appreciated

**UPDATE**

This request works (no callback url specified at all):

```
POST https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token HTTP/1.1
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="----myconsumerkey----", oauth_nonce="r70s1926", oauth_signature="iFGmXEpDav0lVpge9Ls9ACGI6r0%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1503053275", oauth_version="1.0"
```

This request does not (callback url specified, same as twitter app setting):

```
POST https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token HTTP/1.1
Authorization: OAuth oauth_callback="https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com", oauth_consumer_key="----myconsumerkey----", oauth_nonce="707n8282", oauth_signature="0KWzeJwQ%2FNMfmdZ%2Bt0zNEU4g3Ag%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1503053306", oauth_version="1.0"
```

The request above returns:

```
{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}
```

Comment: _“I get the error "Could not authenticate you"”_ - where from? Directly from twitter? Or from your app, after the user returned there?

Comment: Question updated, hope that its just something dumb I'm forgetting to do :)

Comment: I don’t understand why you expect _this_ step to redirect the user anywhere ... that is just a POST request you make in the background, as far as I understand the documentation.

Comment: This step doesnt redirect the user, it simply generates a token, for use with the `authorize` next step. As far as I can tell, the authorize step doesnt have a place to specify the return url to send the user back to the original webpage... so I have assumed that the callback url specified during the auth_token step will be used following a successful `authorize` ?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I used to have it working but now I needed to change my callback url and I'm having the very same problem....

Answer (score 1):

Because exclusion or a setting of oob works it sounds like an encoding problem within the signature generation.

Check that the oauth_callback url is double encoded within your signature base string which should look something like:

```
POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.example.com%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dmyconsumerkey%26oauth_nonce%3D707n8282%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1503057157%26oauth_version%3D1.0
```

Comment: Tried single and double encoding it, but doesnt make a difference to the response. Even tried specifying a relative URL with no effect.

Comment: Strange, as a test try using anything that doesn't have any characters that need to be encoded such as 'www.example.com' and see if that works.